# Apple MDM Push notifications are not delivered to devices

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We are a MDM Vendor for iOS devices. In our device management process, we can successfully enroll devices to our mdm server with produced profile. Device token and push magic values are successfully received from device and recorded.

However the iOS devices not receiving MDM wakeup push notifications. We use new APNS HTTP2 api should be used. However with this new APNS api my devices are not receiving mdm push notifications. I also sending curl command to show my way to send push notifications. APNS server returns 200 http code as response. To note we successfully create customer APNS certificate.

curl -v -d '{"mdm":"08D33A0A-C9DA-461A-AA1F-2868C27927EF"}' -H "apns-topic: com.apple.mgmt.External.de9c0e88-d0ad-41b8-8be2-93587274c01c" -H "apns-priority: 10" -H "apns-expiration: 0" -H "apns-push-type: mdm" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "host: api.push.apple.com" --http2 --cert customer.pem --key customerPrivateKey.key https://api.push.apple.com/3/device/700E36D785BFBF51D1E05C4D383CFA22CC9442523F64EEF01361ECE80686F011

On devices logs there is no mdmd information about received the push notifications and trying to contact with mdm server.

Any help?

Regards,

Aydın